# Is it possible to separate Lead(II) sulfate from sulfuric acid?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

To prepare lead(II) sulfate $\ce{PbSO4}$ from lead(II) carbonate $\ce{PbCO3}$, can I add excess sulfuric acid to lead(II) carbonate so that the products formed will be excess acid with lead(II) sulfate salts? Is it possible to separate lead(II) sulfate from the acid to obtain the pure salts?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead(II)_sulfate tells all you need.

Comment: This might help: https://www.quora.com/Why-is-sulfuric-acid-not-used-to-prepare-lead-sulphate

Comment: The reaction will lead to formation of lead sulfate but what happens is that the lead sulfate formed gets deposited over the lead carbonate and thus it gets disconnected form sulfuric acid and the reaction stops. It happens regardless of the concentration and amount of sulfuric acid used. So, what is done is that lead carbonate is converted to lead nitrate using nitric acid and then it is converted to lead sulfate using sulfuric acid.

Answer (score 0):

Lead sulfate is not soluble in moderately concentrate or dilute sulfuric acid. So a simple filtration will allow the separation lead sulfate - sulfuric acid.